# Using NSolve with Interpolation

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, numerical-methods, interpolation

I'm very new to Mathematica, so sorry if this has an obvious answer, but:

I'm trying to use NSolve to find the point of intersection between two functions, one of which was made using Interpolation, but it won't give me a solution.

Here is the input:

```
data = Table[x, {x, 1, 25, 1}];
data2 = Table[x^.5, {x, 1, 25, 1}];
a1 = Interpolation[Transpose[{data, data2}]];
NSolve[a1[z] == 5 - z^.5, z]
```

And the output:

```
NSolve[InterpolatingFunction[][z] == 5 - z^0.5, z, Reals]
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In[1]:= data = Table[x, {x, 1, 25, 1}];
data2 = Table[x^.5, {x, 1, 25, 1}];
a1 = Interpolation[Transpose[{data, data2}]];
r = z /. FindRoot[a1[z] - (5 - z^.5), {z, 1}];
{r, a1[r], 5 - r^.5}

Out[5]= {6.24994, 2.50001, 2.50001}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I tried my original code, except that I changed NSolve[a1[z] == f[z],...] to FindRoot[a1[z]-f[z],...] and it worked.  However, I have two questions.  First, why does FindRoot work while NSolve fails?  Second, why does your code give me the two extraneous solutions of 2.50?  The actual point at which the two example functions cross is 6.25 and 6.25 only, as can be easily seen graphically.

Comment: FindRoot and NSolve and Solve and Reduce and FindMinimum and Minimze and NMinimize and even more functions in Mathematica all work in slightly different ways. Exactly why one of these will work and another won't is perhaps a little more advanced than you are up to at the moment.  My code didn't give you two extraneous solutions, if you look at my last line of code I show you the root and the value you get if you plug that root into the first of your functions and the the value if you plug that root into the second of your functions. I hoped you would see that this root really did work.

Comment: All right, I understand the last line of code now.  I didn't look closely enough.  Thanks much!